# OfficeJS Excel 2013 - Login flow in IE protected mode

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I just want to see if anyone ran into the following scenario where we are facing couple of issues.
scenario:-
User clicks a button with in addin webapp, popup opens up with a predefined login flow, once login is completed, token returns back to addin webapp and remaining application flow continues.

Couple of issues we are facing are ...
If we dont set/use IE in protected mode, the app doesn't seem to return the control back to the addin. Without token, we can't let the user continue.
So if we use  IE in protected mode, we are facing issues like 
1. the web UI app calls with excel API doesn't seem to work properly. Especially, binding and events.
2. The internal calls from web UI to rest services doesnt work properly.

Just wondering if you guys have any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using window.open directly to create a pop-up then the behavior you described is expected; that is how IE behaves with different integrity level (which is essentially what happens when 2 sites are in different security zones).

If you are using the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync) to create a dialog, for rich clients, like Excel for Windows Desktop, then you should not experience this issue as the process that we create is on the same integrity level as the parent (usually a taskpane). So give that a go.